# Cómo mostrar datos de un array con PDO sin que se dupliquen?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, pdo, arraylist

Tengo un ejercicio para hacer sobre una agenda electrónica donde muestro las horas, horas del turno y paciente y el botón de eliminar. Mi conexión es por método PDO:

```
try{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda_facundo", "root","",
     array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8"));
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Hay error".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Pero no se porque el `foreach` me multiplica los horarios. Éste es el código que tengo para mostrar los datos:

```
          $x=0;
          while ( $x < 25) {
            foreach($turno as $dato ){
            if (($dato->HORA_INICIO == $hora_s[$x]) && ($dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL == $sucursalDrop) && ($dato->PROFESIONAL == $PROfesional)) {
      ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo  $dato->HORA_INICIO  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $dato->HORA_INICIO ?> a <?php echo $dato->HORA_FINAL  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo  $dato->NOMBRE_PACIENTE  ?> [ <?php echo  $dato->TRATAMIENTO ?>, <?php echo $dato->ZONA  ?>, <?php echo $dato->EQUIPO ?>]</td>
                <td><a href="eliminar_turno.php?id=<?php echo $dato->ID_TURNO ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
                <?php  }
                else{
                  
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $hora_s[$x] ?></td>
                 <td>TURNO LIBRE</td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $x++; }  
                
              ?>
```

Alguien me podría dar una manito con esto por favor?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si fuera lo antes posible mejor porque tengo que seguir con el diseño de la pagina jejeje, desde ya muchísimas gracias :3

Comment: Me pregunto por qué la consulta SQL te arroja datos duplicados. Quizá tengas redundancia de datos o un modelo de datos mal diseñado. Si es así, tienes un grave problema sin resolver y en la medida en que la base de datos crezca empezará a haber bloqueos, funcionamiento lento de tu aplicación, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mira, así sería aplicando el array_filter, puedes intentar de esta manera. No pude hacer la prueba ejecutando el código, pero te debería funcionar:
`<?php
$x = 0;
while ($x < 25) {

```
$turnosFiltrados = array_filter($turno, function ($dato) use ($hora_s, $x, $sucursalDrop, $PROfesional) {
    return ($dato->HORA_INICIO == $hora_s[$x]) && ($dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL == $sucursalDrop) && ($dato->PROFESIONAL == $PROfesional);
});
if ($turnosFiltrados) {
    $dato = current($turnosFiltrados);
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $dato->HORA_INICIO ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato->HORA_INICIO ?> a <?php echo $dato->HORA_FINAL ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dato->NOMBRE_PACIENTE ?> [ <?php echo $dato->TRATAMIENTO ?>, <?php echo $dato->ZONA ?>
        , <?php echo $dato->EQUIPO ?>]
    </td>
    <td><a href="eliminar_turno.php?id=<?php echo $dato->ID_TURNO ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i
                class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $hora_s[$x] ?></td>
        <td>TURNO LIBRE</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
$x++;
```

} ?>
`

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias genio.